# How do I calling Classes function in another function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

This is a code in classes

```
addUser (id,name,email,password,mobile)
{
    // Creating a new instance of User with the details provided
    let newUser = new User(id,name,email,password,mobile);
    // Adding the new instance of User into the Accounts array 
    this._accounts.push(newUser);
}
```

i need to call the adduser name how i write the code, down if my code but wrong alrady

```
function(){
let i=0;
adduse(newuser(name))=i;
}
```

Comment: Is `addUser ` a method on a class?

Comment: So what is `adduse(newuser(name))=i;` supposed to do?? What is newuser?

Comment: when user create a name data will store into the classes